# CryptoJS AES encrypted param fails on decrypt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, encryption, cryptojs

On a React app I'm trying to grab some content from some API, encode an object using CryptoJS, then redirecting to another page adding the hash as a param.
On the landing page I'm struggling with an *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse*
Here's the page where I encrypt the API response:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import codeAPI from '../../services/promo-code.api'

const PromoNew = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const params = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await codeAPI.get('code');
      
      const toEncrypt = {
         code : response.data[0].code,            // string
         date : response.data[0].expiration_date, // string
         limit : response.data[0].usage_limit,    // number
      }
      
      const encrypted = encodeURIComponent(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
        JSON.stringify(toEncrypt),
        process.env.REACT_APP_CODE_SECRET
      ).toString());
    
      history.push(`promo/${encrypted}`);
    }

    fetchData();
    
  }, [history, params.code]);

  return (
   // some foo
  )
}

export default PromoNew;
```

And the page where I recieve the encrypted hash as a param:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const Promo = () => {
  const params = useParams();

  const [code, setCode] = useState(null);
  const [expirationDate, setExpirationDate] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      params.hash,
      process.env.REACT_APP_CODE_SECRET
    );
    
    const decrypted = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

    if(!decrypted) {
      setCode('não disponível')
    } else {
      setCode(decrypted);
      setExpirationDate(decrypted.exp);
    }
    
  }, [params.hash]);

  return (
    // some bar
  )
}

export default Promo;
```

> quote Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope. :)

Comment: From your posted code it is not clear if `params.hash` is correctly filled. If it contains the ciphertext from the encryption, i.e. `encrypted`, the URL decoding is missing: `decodeURIComponent(...)`.

Comment: It was missing the ```decodeURIComponent(...)```. Also, converted into an Array the ```toEncrypt``` object and now it passed on all the tests applied. Thanks @Topaco for helping this junior dev. All the best.